# How to add data to a dict-like Item Field using ItemLoaders?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy's XPathItemLoader, but it's api only documents adding values to an Item Field, but not any deeper :( I mean:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    loader = XPathItemLoader(response=response)
    loader.add_xpath('name', '//h1')
```

Will add the values found by the xpath to `Item.name`, but how to add them to `Item.profile['name']`?

Comment: Has the answer helped to solve the problem? Is there anything to improve? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`XPathItemLoader.add_xpath` doesn't support writing to nested fields. You should construct your `profile` dict manually and write it via `add_value` method (in case you still need to go with loaders). Or, you can write your own custom loader.

Here's an example using `add_value`:

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class TestItem(Item):
    others = Field()


class WikiSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["en.wikipedia.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"]


    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        loader = XPathItemLoader(item=TestItem(), response=response)

        others = {}
        crawled_items = hxs.select('//div[@id="mp-other"]/ul/li/b/a')
        for item in crawled_items:
            href = item.select('@href').extract()[0]
            name = item.select('text()').extract()[0]
            others[name] = href

        loader.add_value('others', others)
        return loader.load_item()
```

Run it via: `scrapy runspider <script_name> --output test.json`.

The spider collects items of `Other areas of Wikipedia` from the main wikipedia page and writes it to the dictionary field `others`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is default setting of `scrapy.loader.Itemloader`:

```
class ItemLoader(object):

    default_item_class = Item
    default_input_processor = Identity()
    default_output_processor = Identity()
    default_selector_class = Selector
```

when you use `add_value` `add_xpath` `add_css`, the input and output processor are `Identity()`, which means do nothing. so you can use `add value`:

```
name = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract_first()
loader.add_value('profile', {'name':name})
```